# Best way to tell if datetime string returned from MySQL is empty?

Tags: php, date

A datetime field that is not set in MySQL will return as **0000-00-00 00:00:00**

Whats the best way to determine if the date is not set in PHP?

None if these work:

```
if($date) //will return true because it is a valid string
if(empty($date)) //will also return true.
if(strtotime($date)) //I thought this would work but it returns a negative number and is true.
```

I could use:

```
if($date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

However, if I then ever changed the column type to just **Date** it would break. So I don't like this either.

I was looking for something like `is_date` but all I could find is a function called **checkdate** that doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.

I suppose I could use:

```
if(strtotime($date) > 0)
```

I don't see any obvious problems with this, but I still thought there might be something better.

What is the standard way?

Comment: Can you change the default value of the db field? You could use DEFAULT NULL in the field definition.

Answer (score 5):

```
$dbDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

if (strtotime($dbDate) == 0){
  echo 'Empty date';
}
```

http://www.ideone.com/eNffC

Comment: This does not work, it returns a negative number. Please see here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/8bFVqB

Comment: @JohnIsaacks: Has to be a timezone settings, I get a false value back. Testing `if(!strtotime($dbDate)){ }` would confirm an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((int)$dbDate) echo 'Date is set';
```

for the unix epoch transformations-based solution there can be some timezone-related issues.

Comment: Not particularly reliable, if the datetime field has just the time portion set, e.g. `0000-00-00 12:34:56`. Not likely, but still a possibility.

Comment: 0000-00-00 12:34:56 doesn't seem a valid date for me.